# How to control LayoutBuilder re-building widgets - Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I use LayoutBuilder to control the view when the orientation changes, but it rebuilds the view with every change like when a keyboard is up. How can I control when to re-build the widget only when orientation changes?

```
class ExampleScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
      double screenHeight = constraints.maxHeight;
      double screenWidth = constraints.maxWidth;

      ///this function checks the orientation of the device, and it's used
      ///for the rebuild of the LayoutBuilder to fit both portrait and 
      ///landscape orientations
      Get.find<ViewController>().setOrientation(context);

      return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Container(),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `OrientationBuilder`

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
    body: OrientationBuilder(
      builder: (context, orientation) {
        ///  
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the widget reference which will eventually load only that widget which is previously build.  Have a look

```
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ResponsiveLayout extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget mobileBody;
  final Widget tabletBody;
  final Widget desktopBody;

  const ResponsiveLayout({
    super.key,
    required this.mobileBody,
    required this.tabletBody,
    required this.desktopBody,
  });

  @override
  State<ResponsiveLayout> createState() => _ResponsiveLayoutState();
}

class _ResponsiveLayoutState extends State<ResponsiveLayout> {
   static Widget? mobile;
  static  Widget? tablet;
  static  Widget? desktop;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
print("init called ");
    mobile = widget.mobileBody;
     tablet = widget.tabletBody;
     desktop =widget.desktopBody;
     super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant ResponsiveLayout oldWidget) {
    // TODO: implement didUpdateWidget
    // static const mobile = widget.mobileBody
    // static const tablet = widget.tabletBody
    // static const desktop =widget.desktopBody
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        log(constraints.maxWidth.toString());
        print("rebuilded");
        if (constraints.maxWidth < 600) {
          return mobile??widget.mobileBody;
        } else if (constraints.maxWidth < 1100) {
          return tablet??widget.tabletBody;
        } else {
          return desktop??widget.desktopBody;
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```